# "Default Reader Site Group" people picker not retrieving SQL FBA users?

Tags: 2007, asp.net, forms-authentication, shared-service-provider

I have an issue with people picker for SQL FBA users in SSP admin site for "My Site Settings" page. I have added provider and role information SSP admin web.config file. And also I added "connection string". Still I have an issue.

If I go to Mysites personal sites. That web application able to pick FBA users. And also able to login SSP admin site with FBA admin user.

Somehow SSP admin site has an issue with picking it.

Please advise me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. app pool identity doesn't have right permission to read from SQL members database (aspnetdb). I gave right permissions not I am able pull them.